# Converting chars to binary in C++

Tags: c++, loops, binary, chars

I wrote this and when I launch it, it gives me all the posibilities. I want it to just give me the one that corresponds with my char I've typed in. Can you tell me what's wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char letter='b';
while(letter!='end')
{
    cout<<"What is the letter you wanna convert?"<<endl;
    cin >> letter;
    if(letter='A') {cout<<"01000001"<<endl;}
    if(letter='B') {cout<<"01000010"<<endl;}
    if(letter='C') {cout<<"01000011"<<endl;}
    if(letter='D') {cout<<"01000100"<<endl;}
    if(letter='E') {cout<<"01000101"<<endl;}
    if(letter='F') {cout<<"01000110"<<endl;}
    if(letter='G') {cout<<"01000111"<<endl;}
    if(letter='H') {cout<<"01001000"<<endl;}
    if(letter='I') {cout<<"01001001"<<endl;}
    if(letter='J') {cout<<"01001010"<<endl;}
    if(letter='K') {cout<<"01001011"<<endl;}
    if(letter='L') {cout<<"01001100"<<endl;}
    if(letter='M') {cout<<"01001101"<<endl;}
    if(letter='N') {cout<<"01001110"<<endl;}
    if(letter='O') {cout<<"01001111"<<endl;}
    if(letter='P') {cout<<"01010000"<<endl;}
    if(letter='Q') {cout<<"01010001"<<endl;}
    if(letter='R') {cout<<"01010010"<<endl;}
    if(letter='S') {cout<<"01010011"<<endl;}
    if(letter='T') {cout<<"01010100"<<endl;}
    if(letter='U') {cout<<"01010101"<<endl;}
    if(letter='V') {cout<<"01010110"<<endl;}
    if(letter='W') {cout<<"01010111"<<endl;}
    if(letter='X') {cout<<"01011000"<<endl;}
    if(letter='Y') {cout<<"01011001"<<endl;}
    if(letter='Z') {cout<<"01011010"<<endl;}

    if(letter='a') {cout<<"01100001"<<endl;}
    if(letter='b') {cout<<"01100010"<<endl;}
    if(letter='c') {cout<<"01100011"<<endl;}
    if(letter='d') {cout<<"01100100"<<endl;}
    if(letter='e') {cout<<"01100101"<<endl;}
    if(letter='f') {cout<<"01100110"<<endl;}
    if(letter='g') {cout<<"01100111"<<endl;}
    if(letter='h') {cout<<"01101000"<<endl;}
    if(letter='i') {cout<<"01101001"<<endl;}
    if(letter='j') {cout<<"01101010"<<endl;}
    if(letter='k') {cout<<"01101011"<<endl;}
    if(letter='l') {cout<<"01101100"<<endl;}
    if(letter='n') {cout<<"01101110"<<endl;}
    if(letter='o') {cout<<"01101111"<<endl;}
    if(letter='p') {cout<<"01110000"<<endl;}
    if(letter='q') {cout<<"01110001"<<endl;}
    if(letter='r') {cout<<"01110010"<<endl;}
    if(letter='s') {cout<<"01110011"<<endl;}
    if(letter='t') {cout<<"01110100"<<endl;}
    if(letter='u') {cout<<"01110101"<<endl;}
    if(letter='v') {cout<<"01110110"<<endl;}
    if(letter='w') {cout<<"01110111"<<endl;}
    if(letter='x') {cout<<"01111000"<<endl;}
    if(letter='y') {cout<<"01111001"<<endl;}
    if(letter='z') {cout<<"01111010"<<endl;}
    getche();
}
return 666;
```

}

Comment: Find out how to turn on warnings in your compiler/IDE.

Comment: @infiltrait0rN77, If you have so many `if` statement it is better to use `switch` and just check the cases. like `switch (letter) {case 'A': cout<<"01000001"<<endl; break; ... }`

Answer (score 8):

As for your title, and ignoring the trivial errors in your code, the easiest solution is

```
cout<<"What is the letter you wanna convert?"<<endl;
cin >> letter;
cout << bitset<8>(letter).to_string() << endl;
```

No need for hard coded conversion.

---

Also note, if this question was about academic reasons, and you're asked to develop a solution to generate the string using a generic algorithm, your solution would gain an ***F*** school note from me.

You've been probably expected to use `℅2` modulo operations correctly within a loop (wasn't that part of your recent lectures?).

If not, I'd strongly recommend to go with the [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) solution, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Nah, just me fooling around. Thanks for your response. :)

Comment: @Infiltrait0rN77 Updated my answer with more reference.

Answer (score 3):

You want `if (letter == ...)`, not `if (letter = ...)`

"Can you tell me what's wrong here?"

When you do:

```
if (foo = bar)
```

...you are affecting the value `bar` to `foo`. If the resulting `bar` value is non-zero, the condition is true.

Welcome to programming.

Comment: Legion would like to thank you for helping him. :D How come I missed that... Thanks again.

Comment: When your testing against a constant,  a handy idiom is `if (constant == variable)`: It will not compile if you mistyped '='. Sh*t happens, even worse when copy/pasted all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

When you code -

if(a==anything) {statements}, it checks your code, if it is true it executes your statements

When you code -

If( a= anything) {statements} ,then it assigns the value ( anything) to the variable (a) and executes your statements

```
<pre><code>

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{char letter='b';
cout<<"letter --> binary\nenter 0 to exit\n\n";
(letter!='0')
{
cout<<"\nWhat is the letter you wanna convert? - ";
cin >> letter;
if(letter=='A') {cout<<"01000001"<<endl;}
if(letter=='B') {cout<<"01000010"<<endl;}
if(letter=='C') {cout<<"01000011"<<endl;}
if(letter=='D') {cout<<"01000100"<<endl;}
if(letter=='E') {cout<<"01000101"<<endl;}
if(letter=='F') {cout<<"01000110"<<endl;}
if(letter=='G') {cout<<"01000111"<<endl;}
if(letter=='H') {cout<<"01001000"<<endl;}
if(letter=='I') {cout<<"01001001"<<endl;}
if(letter=='J') {cout<<"01001010"<<endl;}
if(letter=='K') {cout<<"01001011"<<endl;}
if(letter=='L') {cout<<"01001100"<<endl;}
if(letter=='M') {cout<<"01001101"<<endl;}
if(letter=='N') {cout<<"01001110"<<endl;}
if(letter=='O') {cout<<"01001111"<<endl;}
if(letter=='P') {cout<<"01010000"<<endl;}
if(letter=='Q') {cout<<"01010001"<<endl;}
if(letter=='R') {cout<<"01010010"<<endl;}
if(letter=='S') {cout<<"01010011"<<endl;}
if(letter=='T') {cout<<"01010100"<<endl;}
if(letter=='U') {cout<<"01010101"<<endl;}
if(letter=='V') {cout<<"01010110"<<endl;}
if(letter=='W') {cout<<"01010111"<<endl;}
if(letter=='X') {cout<<"01011000"<<endl;}
if(letter=='Y') {cout<<"01011001"<<endl;}
if(letter=='Z') {cout<<"01011010"<<endl;}

if(letter=='a') {cout<<"01100001"<<endl;}
if(letter=='b') {cout<<"01100010"<<endl;}
if(letter=='c') {cout<<"01100011"<<endl;}
if(letter=='d') {cout<<"01100100"<<endl;}
if(letter=='e') {cout<<"01100101"<<endl;}
if(letter=='f') {cout<<"01100110"<<endl;}
if(letter=='g') {cout<<"01100111"<<endl;}
if(letter=='h') {cout<<"01101000"<<endl;}
if(letter=='i') {cout<<"01101001"<<endl;}
if(letter=='j') {cout<<"01101010"<<endl;}
if(letter=='k') {cout<<"01101011"<<endl;}
if(letter=='l') {cout<<"01101100"<<endl;}
if(letter=='n') {cout<<"01101110"<<endl;}
if(letter=='o') {cout<<"01101111"<<endl;}
if(letter=='p') {cout<<"01110000"<<endl;}
if(letter=='q') {cout<<"01110001"<<endl;}
if(letter=='r') {cout<<"01110010"<<endl;}
if(letter=='s') {cout<<"01110011"<<endl;}
if(letter=='t') {cout<<"01110100"<<endl;}
if(letter=='u') {cout<<"01110101"<<endl;}
if(letter=='v') {cout<<"01110110"<<endl;}
if(letter=='w') {cout<<"01110111"<<endl;}
if(letter=='x') {cout<<"01111000"<<endl;}
if(letter=='y') {cout<<"01111001"<<endl;}
if(letter=='z') {cout<<"01111010"<<endl;}
getch();
}
return 666;}
```

Comment: Your explanation is incomplete and does not actually explain the simple typo. Also, the code is formatted oddly.

Comment: Don't put details in comments! [Edit] the Answer and make your changes there. Answers should be stand-alone and comments can be deleted. I didn't ask for you to explain it to _me_ in a comment, but rather present your answer in a clear and obvious way for _everyone_. (And to fix the broken formatting.) See [answer]. (BTW, your explanation isn't quite right anyway. Do you know _why_ is `f=anything` returning true?)

Comment: Ok, thanks for  suggesting